# After having set up a Mozilla sync server, what are the next steps?

Tags: firefox, passwords, sync, bookmarks

I'd like to synchronize bookmarks (and eventually passwords) between multiple Firefox installations on a local network (4 PCs).

I have followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver) and think that I have the server up and running (there are no error messages when I do `make serve`, and if I enter the respective URL into Firefox's address bar, a page appears which has the text "It works" in small letters at the upper left corner).

I have changed the preferences in every Firefox installation as advised in the tutorial. From that point on, I am completely lost. The tutorial says:

> Firefox should now sync against your local server rather than the
>   default Mozilla-hosted servers.

But how can I make Firefox do the synchronization? There is no menu item, and the database `syncserver.db` on the server obviously even doesn't get updated when I close and restart Firefox on all clients.

I am missing something very basic here ...